# Can't save image header data using pyexifinfo

Tags: python, image, header

I'm using the `pyexifinfo` library to extract header info from an image. The code I've got is as follows:

```
import pyexifinfo as Z
import json

f = open('header_infdo.txt','w')

data = p.get_json("img.jpg")
formatted_data =(( json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True,indent=4, separators=(',', ':')) ))

print(formatted_data)

s = str(formatted_data)

f.write(s)
f.close
```

I've put the `print` function in to verify that I am extracting the data (which occurs successfully), but when I open the file its empty.

The data extracted is as follows:

```
[
{
"Composite:ImageSize":"4096x2304",
"Composite:Megapixels":9.4,
"ExifTool:ExifToolVersion":10.1,
"File:BitsPerSample":8,
"File:ColorComponents":3,
"File:Comment":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<image time=\"15:27:56.763207\" date=\"2016.02.03\" acq_index=\"3692\">\n\t<acquisition>\n\t\t<exposure>10000</exposure>\n\t\t<sensor_digital_gain>4</sensor_digital_gain>\n\t\t<aperture>4</aperture>\n\t\t<focus>68</focus>\n\t\t<digital_gain>1</digital_gain>\n\t\t<name>Photo_pose</name>\n\t\t<camera_session_name>EXI-55-retest-3</camera_session_name>\n\t</acquisition>\n\t<errors>\n\t\t<error>\n\t\t\t<name>ntp_status_check</name>\n\t\t\t<subsystem>NTP</subsystem>\n\t\t\t<message>NTP is not synced or offset is too long</message>\n\t\t\t<extra>Offset: 0ms threshold: 5msWhen: 0ms threshold: 5ms</extra>\n\t\t\t<timestamp>2016-Feb-03 15:27:47.830965</timestamp>\n\t\t\t<alert>false</alert>\n\t\t\t<clearable>false</clearable>\n\t\t</error>\n\t</errors>\n</image>\n",
    "File:Directory":"C:/Users/richie/Desktop/work",
    "File:EncodingProcess":"Baseline DCT, Huffman coding",
    "File:FileAccessDate":"2016:02:10 18:31:14+00:00",
    "File:FileCreateDate":"2016:02:10 18:31:14+00:00",
    "File:FileModifyDate":"2016:02:08 18:42:47+00:00",
    "File:FileName":"img.jpg",
    "File:FilePermissions":"rw-rw-rw-",
    "File:FileSize":"1422 kB",
    "File:FileType":"JPEG",
    "File:FileTypeExtension":"jpg",
    "File:ImageHeight":2304,
    "File:ImageWidth":4096,
    "File:MIMEType":"image/jpeg",
    "File:YCbCrSubSampling":"YCbCr4:2:0 (2 2)",
    "JFIF:JFIFVersion":1.02,
    "JFIF:ResolutionUnit":"None",
    "JFIF:XResolution":1,
    "JFIF:YResolution":1,
    "SourceFile":"C:/Users/richie/Desktop/work/img.jpg"
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I need to stop answering my own questions :)
include the parentheses in `f.close()`